# Rough idle just at start

Tags: engine, chevrolet, overheating, rough-idle, silverado

The engine on my '04 Chevy Silverado 1500 recently overheated. It now has a rough idle when I start it, which disappears almost completely once I drive it a bit and it gets warmed up. What could be the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are there any codes present? (Check engine light on?) If so, what are they?

Comment: That's the weird part. After overheating I got a check engine light with codes showing misfires on 6 cylinders. I cleared that but it came back. Now it went off again (on it's own) and has been off for a couple days.

Comment: Is it still missing when cold?

Comment: Yes, but with no engine light coming on.

Comment: When it overheated, how hot did it get? What exactly happened when it overheated? Have you checked the coolant levels? When you start it up, do you see excess smoke/steam from the exhaust?

Comment: I really don't know how hot it got because it was parked and idling when it happened. It stopped, probably stalled, I wasn't around so I don't know what noises it made before stopping. The headlights were on so the battery was dead when I came to it. The next day I pulled it in the shop to warm up (it was -15 outside) then started it after a couple hours. It had a rough time starting and even stalled a couple times when driving it, but it's not doing that anymore. I don't see excess smoke, nor do I see coolant in oil or vice versa, or any other signs of a blown head gasket.

Comment: Coolant tank was empty, have since refilled and it's maintaining level and functioning properly.

Comment: My thinking is, it's leaking coolant into the cylinders, just enough to cause the rough running at startup. Then once the coolant which has accumulated in the cylinders has cleared up, the engine can run without any issue, even though there may be more coolant entering the cylinders. This is just a hunch on my part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141583/discussion-between-geo-and-ps2).